# Inequality with binomial coefficient ${n \choose \left[{\frac{n+m}{2}}\right]}\geq \frac{2^{n+1/2}}{\sqrt{n-p/2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a natural number, $m\in [-n, n]$. Let $p=0,\ldots, \frac{n+m}{2}$.

Show, that for all $p$,
$${n \choose \left[{\frac{n+m}{2}}\right]}\geq \frac{2^{n+1/2}}{\sqrt{n-p/2}}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is this $N$ that suddenly pops up?

Comment: @Alex, do you mean $\forall n,m>N$?

Comment: Sorry it suppose to be $n$ instead of $N$.

Comment: If $m=n$ and $p={n+m\over 2}=n$, then the right hand side is infinite....

Comment: Sorry, its one more typo-it should be $p/2$ under the square root.

Comment: Now if $m=n$ and $p={m+n\over 2}$, then the right hand side is way bigger than the left hand side.